# IIS WCF Service authentication, javascript client

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, iis

What is the best (or at least one that works) option to secure a IIS hosted REST WCF service that will be called by javascript clients?

The service that I have is a REST service that receives GETs and POSTs from the clients and it's working fine, through http and https.

I've been trying to implement authentication, and I have a database with my own structure for users and roles and the such (so I want to avoid Windows authentication)
I've been trying different things but I can't get anything to work.

Last thing I've tried is Basic Authentication (Transport) with a ServiceAuthorizationManager and UserName Auth (Message) with a custom validator.

I don't know if I can use the custom validator (inheriting from System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator) with Basic authentication, or if I can add UserName authentication credentials in the http(s) REST requests (maybe it needs to be a SOAP service?).

Also I would like to use something like a custom RoleProvider to control method access based on user groups /roles .

Thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer but I am following your question as I have an upcoming project that is very similiar. I have this saved on the horizon as I know I want to implement token auth, it may be worth a read or may be useless for your needs. Couldn't hurt to share though. http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/

Comment: @TravisActon I don't think it's exactly what I need, but thanks anyway. I think I finally got it right. A main problem was that I wasn't able to get past the first authentication without a Windows user and I had custom users. If it works as intended, I will post the relevant code as an answer

Comment: It is highly recommend that you force HTTPS when using basic authentication - otherwise your user credentials will be sent by the client in plain-text over the network.

Comment: Do you need WCF ? WebAPI is way easier if http(s) + REST is all you care about.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to do this:

**1. Using Client Certificate Authentication.

See these articles:**

- [Securing WCF Services with Certificates](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28248/Securing-WCF-Services-with-Certificates).
- [Use Certificate Authentication and Message Security in WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx)

You can authorise your clients based on the certificate they pass (using thumbprint) and you can categorise them easily.

**2. Implement Basic authentication with SQL Membership Provider**.

Refer these articles:

- [WCF Basic Authentication with SQL Membership Provider](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379636/WCF-Basic-Authentication-with-SQL-Membership-Provi)
- [Use Username Authentication with the SQL Server Membership Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647294.aspx)

You will have to take a call on what best serves your purpose and what will be easier to maintain in future. Certificate management is a pain most of the times, however it has its own set of advantages. I personally would go with the second option which is using **Basic Auth with SQL membership provider**.